# Custom IP over an AXI bus

Tags: fpga, xilinx, amba

I have a Xilinx Zybo board. I followed the instructions [here](http://www.fpgadeveloper.com/2014/08/creating-a-custom-ip-block-in-vivado.html) and created a custom multiplier over the AXI bus. The multiplier shown on the website processes one input and generates one output. How can I modify it such that it can process streaming inputs sort of like a pipeline. Any hints?

Comment: This is a better question for the Electrical Engineering exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tutorial, at Step 5 of "Create the custom IP", select AXI Stream interface rather than AXI Lite.  Then modify the HDL source to have the proper signals for a streaming interface (mainly VALID, READY, and DATA).  Then follow the rest of the steps to add the IP into your design in Vivado.

Note you'll have to create 2 streaming interfaces, one for input and one for output.  Unlike AXI Lite where you can read/write a single register, a Stream is a one-directional flow of data.

EDIT: this doesn't address the way you'd test/stim from the SW side.  The example will only work with an AXI Lite interface.  You'd need a custom driver to work with the Streaming IF(s)